# What is the transformation of Moebius that commands $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$ in $z_1'$, $z_2'$, $z_3'$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to find the general way to send any $3$ points in another $3$ points, with a transformation of Mobius

I think it could be done this way:

$$f_1(z_1)= 0,\quad
f_1(z_2)=1,\quad
f_1(z_3)= \infty$$

and

$$f_2(z_1')= 0,\quad
f_2(z_2')=1,\quad
f_2(z_3')= \infty.$$

And then the funcion is $f_2^{-1}$ composition $f_1$

but I can not get the explicit form, especially when taking the inverse
Can you help me?

Comment: so far you are correct. Also, to get the inverse, just take the inverse matrix of the coefficient matrix; except it is not necessary to divide by the determinant, so the "adjoint" matrix is good enough.

Comment: If $[a,b:c,d]$ is the cross-ratio, then it is invartiant under Moebius transfrom and hence $[z_1,z_2:z_3,z]=[z_1',z_2':z_3',z']$ is the equation relating $z$ to $z'$. This is equivalent to what you suggested. Just solve for $z'$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is correct.

Now try to write $f_1$ in the form $f_1(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ and $f_2$ in the form $f_2(z)=\frac{a'z+b'}{c'z+d'}$.

Once you have this, rewrite in matrix form:

$T=\begin{bmatrix}
a\ b\\c\ d\end{bmatrix}$ and $S=\begin{bmatrix}
a' \ b'\\c'\ d'\end{bmatrix}$

And the desired transformation would be $U(z)=S^{-1}\circ T(z),$ $U(z)=\frac{ez+f}{gz+h}$

(Note that you can find $S^{-1}\circ T$ multiplying the 2 matrix $ S^{-1}T$)

---

Second note: In this case, $\displaystyle S^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
\ \ d' \ -b'\\-c'\ \ \ a'\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Ok I found this: $ \varphi(z)=\frac{z-z_2}{z-z_4}* \frac{z_3-z_4}{z_3-z_2}$ So now I have to make the corresponding products to see it as $\frac{az + b} {cz + d}$?
I'm sorry, I'm very bad with this

Comment: Well assuming that $z_2\to0,z_4\to\infty, z_3\to1$, notice that $\varphi(z)=\frac{z-z_2}{z-z_4}* \frac{z_3-z_4}{z_3-z_2}$ has already the form $\frac{az + b} {cz + d}$, you can call $\alpha=\frac{z_3-z_4}{z_3-z_2}$, thus you have: $\varphi(z)=\frac{\alpha z-\alpha z_2}{1z-z_4}$ which looks like $\frac{az + b} {cz + d}$

Comment: Ok thanks!!! :)

Comment: @JazmínJones I updated my answer.